# Comparing URLs in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, url

I have an application that crawls a web site for unique link urls (i.e. hrefs) and then saves the urls to a database. I will ensure that there is url for each page in the site. Below is the code for getting the string that is saved to the database.

```
'url is the url obtained from the link's href
Dim uriReturn As Uri = New Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)

'Make it absolute if it's relative
If Not uriReturn.IsAbsoluteUri Then
     Dim baseUri As New Uri(BaseUrl)
     uriReturn = New Uri(baseUri, uriReturn)
End If

Return LCase(uriReturn.ToString)
```

In another part of the application I have section that queries the database with the url of the current page. Below is the code for getting the current page url.

```
Dim CurrentURL As String = lcase(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

My question is can I be sure that I will find a match in the database using the current page url? That is could there be differences in the string obtained from the href and the string returned from the current page even through they point to the same page? Is there a way to convert the urls to ensure they will always match?

Comment: Can you give a an example of a difference between _"the string obtained from the href and the string returned from the current page"_?

Comment: Converting the url to lowercase could break the url, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Since `BaseURl` is not defined, can't tell if you got it correct. But `BaseUrl` should be = `Request.Url`.

And your

```
Dim CurrentURL As String = lcase(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

Since you are doing store/retrieve, I suggests you standardize your methods. In store section, you use `uriReturn.ToString()`, so in the retrieve section, you should also use `ToString()` instead of `AbsoluteUri`.

Comment: I use either the base element reference in the page or the request url. And is it important that I use ToString() when the absoluteuri is a string and uriReturn must be converted to a string? Or is it just a matter of convention?

Comment: It's just a matter of best-practice. You'll never know who debugs your program 6 months down the road. At least the 2 piece of codes sync :)